# Statistical analysis of number of flood events

Tags: hypothesis-testing, poisson-distribution, offset

I am given the number of flooding events. There were 9 events in the years 2000-2010, and 6 between 1900-2000. How can one use Poisson to test if the frequency is increasing or not? What other type of statistical test can be used to know if the frequency is increasing or decreasing?

---

The dataset is 1990 to 2012 and the range i used was 10 years apiece  and the number of occurrence of flood in the first ten years 1990-2000 was 6 while in the second was 9 times. my question was to find out weather the frequency is increasing or decreasing and plotting the graph using R-Stat and Possion statistical test

Comment: i need detail explanation and the R-stat working with the graph

Answer (score 1):

*Updated to reflect clarified problem statement.*

Without more data you will not be able to check the validity of the assumption that your data are truly Poisson.  That is, most count data is overdispersed relative to the Poisson distribution (if true for your data, accounting for that correctly would reduce your significance relative to using the Poisson).  If you are willing to make that assumption, then using the Poisson distribution makes it possible to test these data without more information.

Here is an example, coded in `R`:

```r
poisson.test(x=c(6,9), T=10)
#  Comparison of Poisson rates
# 
# data:  c(6, 9) time base: 10
# count1 = 6, expected count1 = 7.5, p-value = 0.6072
# alternative hypothesis: true rate ratio is not equal to 1
# 95 percent confidence interval:
#  0.1952634 2.0972240
# sample estimates:
# rate ratio 
# 0.6666667
```

Comment: I believe the 1900 was a typo.  Before you edited it, there was one line saying 1990-2010 for the whole dataset.

Comment: That's a reasonable point, @jlimahaverford. The original version wasn't very coherent, so I made some guesses about what the real situation was. I may well have guessed incorrectly.  I will update this to address the other possibility.